# Separate data received from various senders in Veins/OMNET++

Tags: omnet++, veins

In my scenario, a receiving vehicle gets BSMs from multiple senders. I need the BSM data recorded separately according to their respective senders.

Currently, I am achieving this using a custom logging system. However, since OMNET++ has a sophisticated logging system built-in, Is it possible to achieve what I need using OMNET's built-in tools?

Answer (score 0):

OMNeT++ vectors log 2-tuples (TV: time+value) or 3-tuples (ETV: event+time+value) for each piece of data. You can use this additional information to find which values have been recorded at the same simulation time or as a consequence of the same event.